# Not able to install application from store device

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have setup WSO 2 emm 2.0.1 . I have published two public applications via publisher console. And then done enterprise install of the applications for some of the users from store console with admin credentials. Now the applications are visible in My subscription tab store If I login with users credentials. If I try to install applications on the device by clicking on application it gives an error as none of your devices are enrolled.

Comment: are there any devices enrolled on EMM?

Comment: Yes device is enrolled And if I open store URL from laptop it gives pop-up to select a device . Same is not working from enrolled device.